# Datatype error when summing column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using this query to sum two columns

```
REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),cast(round(isnull(sum(R1.[Dollars] + R.[Current Cost]),0),0)as MONEY),1), '.00', '') as [Total Cost],
```

Dollars column has null values.

But I get this error

> Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator

Can anyone correct me?

Comment: R1.[Dollars] and R.[Current      Cost] -- which one is nvarchar?

Comment: If you have **numerical** values and you want to `SUM` them up - why are you using `NVARCHAR` ?!?!??! Doesn't make **any sense at all** - if you have numbers - use a numeric datatype like `INT` or `DECIMAL` !

Comment: @dean - current cost is nvarchar

Comment: What are you doing isn't sql server responsibility. It is  responsibility of your clients presentation layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you reformat the statement you see how many operations are being done:

```
REPLACE( 
    CONVERT(
        VARCHAR(32),
        cast(
            round(
                isnull(
                    sum(R1.[Dollars] + R.[Current Cost])
                    ,0)    -- use 0 for NULL
                ,0)        -- round to 0 decimals
            as MONEY)      -- convert to money
        ,1)                -- convert to string with commas and two digits
     , '.00', '')          -- remove decimals
 as [Total Cost],
```

The root of your problem, is that `[Current Cost]` is not a numeric type!

The *simplest* solution is to just return a numeric type and leave the *formatting* to the clinet:

```
 ISNULL(sum(R1.[Dollars] + CAST(R.[Current Cost] AS MONEY),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

"@dean - current cost is nvarchar " - Vicky

If [Current Cost] is NVARCHAR then that is your problem. You need to CONVERT it to a numeric datatype bfore you can include in your sum(R1.[Dollars] + R.[Current Cost]).

Answer (score 0):

Please sort the data integrity issues in the table, instead of in the all queries.

In other words, instead of casting ad nauseam:

```
REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),cast(round(isnull(sum(R1.[Dollars] + cast(R.[Current      Cost] as decimal(12,4)),0),0)as MONEY),1), '.00', '') as [Total Cost],
```

just change the datatype of the column to an appropriate one. But of course, you already have some un-convertable values in that column, so it's not an easy task, you have to get rid of them first and replace them with some default. And it wouldn't have happened if there were proper datatypes for the columns from the begining.

As an added note, try not using money datatype, unless absolutely certain about it, you're bound to get some weird rounding errors down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column with decimal data type. Update that column with records from current cost column. Then remove the current cost column with data type nvarchar. Rename the new column to current cost. You then don't have to write query for converting values.